# Eclipse not picking up Java Zulu

Tags: java, eclipse, azul-zulu

I have upgraded to Java zulu and my eclipse keep picking up the older java version . I did remove the old jre in java build path and added Zulu . But when I run maven clean and build again , Eclipse picks up the older version by itself . I have path variable set to Zulu version . What am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Select _JRE System Library_ and click **Edit...** button. Then, in the window that opens, click button _Installed JREs..._

Comment: You have to configure the JDKs/JREs in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.